# save button grayed out randomly

Tags: save-post, autosave

Hello wordpress community,

we are facing the issue, that the save-button in wordpress is sometimes greyed-out (and stays that way).
As far as we observed this, this usually happens on the auto-save.

I am aware, that the usual reason for this would be errors in the code, but there are no errors logged in the fpm- or apache-logs.
There is also no indication of a timeout (ie no 408 response code).

The wordpress instance currently has 512 MB of RAM and does not use all of it. It also has more than enough CPU-Power.

My assumption is, that there is either a timeout on the auto-draft-saves or an error of some kind, that does not get logged.

So how would i be able to confirm this/find the error? turning on WP_DEBUG is not an option tho, as there is too much traffic on this backend.

thank you,

best regards,

scones

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: As this happens not all the time, but randomly, there is never a console open. especially since the users of that interface are more focused on the articles and would be rather distracted by an console. but i might consider capturing all js errors and passing them along (similar to what newrelic does)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen as you said there are some errors in code or if there is long or duplicate queries. Try to debug it with [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).
Same reason if Safe button takes longer to get active.

Comment: the problem is occuring *randomly* so this excludes: errors, long running/duplicate queries. also the button does not _take longer_ but stays greyed out.